# How to highlight all occurrence of the patterns in VIM which I have selected through mouse?

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to do something like we have in Notepad++.
If I select particular sentence or word through a mouse then I want to highlight all the occurrence of that sentence in the file. Does anybody gone through this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight all occurrence of a selected word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431184/highlight-all-occurrence-of-a-selected-word)

Comment: Just press `/` and then right click and enter. Or, if you have set incremental search, you can just press `/` and right click.

Answer (score 1):

My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) has (among others) a `:SearchAutoHighlighting` command that turns on highlighting of the current word or selection.

If you're interested in a smaller, more focussed plugin, there are many alternative plugins. Many of them are listed on the plugin page.